# getElementById and display="none" not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html

Any chance someone can see why this isn't working and explain it to me?

I've tried this locally (using xampp) and on JS Bin. Using JS Bin it appears that the div DOES hide, but then comes right back.

Here is my html/code:

```
<div id="maxnum">
<p>What number would you like to count to?</p>
<form>
<input type="number" name="count-to" id="countnum">
<button onclick="alts()">This Number</button>
</form>
</div>
<script>
function alts(){
    mnum=countnum.value;
    document.getElementById('maxnum').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

Comment: The errors you get should help you debug the issue. And what do you expect `countnum` to be?

Comment: The function `alts` is probably not defined when that DOM element is parsed. Moving your `script` to before the `onclick` might help.

Comment: the function needs to be declared above wherever you are calling it from. Also you need to fetch `mnum` by fetching `countnum` by id

Comment: `onclick="alts(this)"` or `var num = this.value;` for starting

Comment: when you click in a button inside a form, the form is submited, what cause a page refresh...

Comment: `onclick="alts(this)"` and `var num = this.value;` for starting

Comment: you don't need this in a `<form>`

Comment: @musically_ut (ignoring the fact the fault has been pointed out multiple times as due to not cancelling the post-back) wouldn't that be the case if `alts()` was being called at that point? In this case, `alts()` is only called on a button click, so the function would exist.

Comment: @freefaller You are correct.

Comment: Another thing is that you have not closed your input tag, the input should be formatted like `<input....../>`

Comment: Thanks!!! Taking it out of the form worked perfect. That all makes sense now.

mnum actually works fine. I added an alert for the mnum variable at the end of the function and when I put a number into the field and click the button, the number is in the alert.

Also, the function works fine at the end of the body and not in the head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clicking the button in your `form` is submitting the form, which cause the page to reload (and hence your hidden div reappears). You need to return `false` from the handle to stop that from happening.

For example:

```
function alts(){
    mnum=countnum.value;
    document.getElementById('maxnum').style.display = 'none';
    return false;    // this stop submission
}
```

And:

```
<button onclick="return alts()">This Number</button>
```

Or if you intention is to *not* ever submit the form, then you don't actually need the `form` tag at all and removing it will solve the problem.

Or, as @WookieCoder pointed out, you can use `input` with type `button` instead of `button` like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="alts()" value="This Number"/>
```

(note using `type="submit"` would give you a button that *does* submit the form).

You can actually even specify a type for the `button`. The default in *most* browsers is `submit`, but you can do this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="alts()">This Number</button>
```

And have a `button` that behaves like a `button` instead of a `submit`.

Comment: Alternatively you could have a type="button", which would prevent the form submit

Answer (score 0):

It comes back because of PostBack.
Return false after you call alts(). It'll prevent post back

```
<button onclick="alts(); return false;">This Number</button>
```